# During integration, I encounter the repeating integrals scenario. When moving the repeating integral to the leftside of the equation it becomes zero.

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate the following by the method of integration by parts:
$$\int_{-L}^L \cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) dx$$

**I did the following steps:**
Using integration by parts: $\int udv = uv -\int vdu $
$$u= \cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}), dv=\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L})$$
then $$du=-\frac{n\pi}{L}.\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}),  v = \frac{L}{m\pi}. \sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L})$$
$$\int_{-L}^L \cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) dx=\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\frac{L}{m\pi} .\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L})-\int_{-L}^L \frac{L}{m\pi} .\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L}).-\frac{n\pi}{L}.\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$

Applying the integration by parts again:
Let $$u = \frac{L}{m\pi} .\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) , dv=-\frac{n\pi}{L}.\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$
then $$du = \frac{L}{m\pi}.\frac{m\pi}{L}.\cos{\frac{m\pi x}{L}} = \cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L}),$$ and $$v = -\frac{n\pi}{L}.\frac{L}{n\pi}.-cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})=cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$
Plugging this, we get:
$$\int_{-L}^L \cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) dx=\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\frac{L}{m\pi} \sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L})-
 \left[\frac{L}{m\pi} \sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L})cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})- \int_{-L}^L cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L})\right]$$
Removing the square brackets and multiplying the minus sign, we get:

$$\int_{-L}^L \cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) dx=\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\frac{L}{m\pi}. \sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L})-\frac{L}{m\pi}. \sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L}).cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})+ \int_{-L}^L cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L})$$
Moving the integrand on the right to the left side of the equation, I got:
$$\int_{-L}^L \cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) dx - \int_{-L}^L cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L})=\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\frac{L}{m\pi} \sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L})-\frac{L}{m\pi} .\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L}).cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) $$

The left side of the equation cancels out:
$$0=\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\frac{L}{m\pi} .\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L})-\frac{L}{m\pi} .\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L}).cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) $$

This is the problem I am facing.
**Background:**
This is one of the three orthogonality equations I encountered in a course.
I tried integrating others as well, and ended up with the same results, (right hand side of the equation becoming zero). The other equation was:$$\int_{-L}^L \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}).\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) dx$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for hours now. Thank you.

Comment: To solve the integral I would suggest werner formulas.

Comment: I think that with your procedure you are somehow reversing the integration by parts formula. Try doing your steps with a generic u amd nu I think can clarify what is happening

Comment: Hint: use $\cos A\cos B=\frac12(\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B))$.

Comment: xpaul's comment is right in the money. These integrasl, so common in harmonic analysis and/or Fourier analysis, are easily done with basic trigonometric identities. Anyway, for $\;n\neq m\;$ , the integral's value is zero since those two cosines are part of an orthogonal system in some Inner product space (I won't continue on this since I'm not sure whether you've studied this stuff in this way).

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for your insights. Can u point me to the resources that would teach such stuff. Like topic names/ course names etc. Thank you

Comment: @xpaul@Thomas I did see some solutions that use the formulas/identities that you have mentioned. I will surely try that, but I am still concerned about why integration by parts is not working? I wanted to know what I am doing wrong in integration by parts because I want to avoid rthe same mistakes in the future. Thank you

Comment: @hamzamohiuddin Any beginners book in Fourier analysis , or even in HArmonic Analysis, should deal with this. You though must first have a heftly 1-2 years of analysis and linear algebra to fully understand (basis, orthogonality, infinite dimensiona linear spaces, series, power series and etc.)

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for your kind advice. Have a good day!